# How to 'slow down' algorithm or how to make pauses during run of algorithms

Tags: javascript, html, time, html5-canvas

I would like to make a teaching portal, where students would learn basics of algorithm. I made line rasterization algorithm in JavaScript and I would like to 'debug' or 'slow down' the algorithm, because it shows what is going on during the algorithm and shows matematics operation behind it. Unfortunately, I am not able to find a way how to do it. When I debug my .js it is working, but it is running so fast, that user is not able to see it. I need something, which will pause the algorithm for a few second and then continues.I tried setTimeout function but it is not working as I expected. I tried to make [sleep function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoPcX.jpg) but it freezes whole algorithm. I read a lot about this and found not the answer. The worst case scenario is add the button and user will push the button and then it will continue(I can think about solution but actually didn't tried it yet). [Here is basic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z0kY.jpg) of my code: You click two points and then algorithm starts. It prints values of variables into canvas and colors the pixels(on the canvas) which are calculated in for cycle.I would like to 'slow down' for cycle for student to see, in which line is algorithm and how it decides which one pixel it colors next. function Highlight()is showing where algorithm is and which values are currently in it-it is not important, I just needs to pause it there for a few seconds and then continues.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think that `setTimeout()` requires a function without parentheses as the first argument. You can't call `Highlight(x)` like that. Instead what you need to do is `setTimeout(function(){Highlight(x)},1000)`.